# Zoom Conference install and launching problem

Tags: zoom-meeting

I Have a problem launching the program in xubuntu.

```
uname -a
4.13.0-38-generic #43~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 14 17:48:43 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

my installation code is:

```
sudo dpkg --install zoom_amd64.deb 
(Reading database ... 209468 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack zoom_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking zoom (2.0.123086.0330) over (2.0.123086.0330) ...
run post uninstall script, action is upgrade ...
Setting up zoom (2.0.123086.0330) ...
run post install script, action is configure...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.5-2ubuntu0.1) ...

shahi@shahi-Inspiron-N4010:~/Downloads$ zoom
ZoomLauncher started.
Zoom not exist at current directory - /home/shahi/Downloads
Zoom path is: /opt/zoom
cmd line: 
$HOME = /home/shahi 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

can you help me with this?

Comment: Do you get the same result when you use the GUI?

Comment: In GUI no warning, nothing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please run following command in your terminal and try running Zoom again:

```
touch ~/.config/zoomus.conf
```

Please let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If touching the config file does not work, check the output of `sudo apt upgrade`. You might see something like:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 zoom : Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx but it is not installed
        Depends: libegl1-mesa but it is not installed
        Depends: libxcb-xtest0 but it is not installed
```

in which case running `apt --fix-broken install` should fix the problem.